# Analytics in Spring boot microservice

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

My requirement is as follows

I have microservice A. This has X db. We need to derive insights of the data present in X db and show graphs, charts and other things in UI. I want to know the best way to do this. Elastic search is good option but as of now we cannot use this in prodcution. Alternative for this I thought is to use redis cache

I want to know if there is any other best way to do analytics in spring boot microservices?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what type of analytics you want to do. If suppose you want to do lots of aggregation; then some RDBMS like MySQL might be a good choice.. Redis/Memcached are most probably NOT the right choice for analytics..

You need to use some DB which gives u direct support of analytic functions u need for example AVERAGE, SUM etc..